# Efficiently detecting objects inside multiple radius

Tags: android, algorithm, game-physics

I would like to create a game for mobile that require to calculate multiple time by seconds which moving objects are in the radius of moving points. The game is highly inspired from Gratuitous Space Battles, the radius being from the weapons. Thus, I would like to know if it's realist to expect to be able to know among 1000 moving objects, in which radius they are among 1000 moving points 100 times per seconds on an average android device. In term of complexity, if there is an algorithm better than O(N.M), N being the number of moving objects and M the number of radius from M moving center and if an algorithm can benefit from the fact that the moving objects are near their precedent position.

Comment: The radius doesn't affect the time complexity, just the number of objects. And no, you won't be able to do better than O(N).

Comment: It's the number of radius, not the radius. There is M radius with M center (x,y) of these radius. Sorry if it was unclear.

Comment: Could you add some precisions about the context?
But if you are asking about collision detection of one element with its neighbours, then implementing a quad-tree (or even better, an R-tree) would be the best way to cut down the number of checks I think.

Comment: It is like a tower defense game where you have to detect if you can fire on ennemy or not. The difference is that the tower are moving and I want to be able to prioritize target on their value that i defined elsewhere than their order of entrance in the radius.

Comment: Is there some maximum movement speed?  If so, then for each object, after computing an exact distance to each weapon in an initial step, it should be possible to keep lower bounds on the distance to each weapon in increasing distance order, and only go as far down this list checking for actual intersections as you need to on each frame.

Comment: There is but the map isn't much bigger than the maximun speed multiplied by a second and I need to be able to know every objects in radius before making a choice.

Comment: @Atol We might be able to exploit it if `M` is much less than `N` or vice versa. Is it the case?

Comment: There is no general case for their relative size.

Comment: I've found answers on gamedev: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/79842/efficiently-detecting-objects-inside-multiple-radius

Comment: It's not the speed multiplied by 1s but the speed multiplied by the duration of 1 frame (1/100 of a second, according to you) that matters.